# Invalidate regions when doublebuffering?

Tags: winforms

Is there any point to call **Invalidate(Region region)** when using the double buffer technic? In the Paint event I still have to draw everything, so it might would be more efficient to just call **Invalidate()**?

Answer (score 0):

You'de better implement the double buffering manually by using [BufferedGraphicsContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphicscontext.aspx) as is explained in this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b367a457.aspx)